# Translation a slogan "the perfect boost" to Chinese

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I try to translate it to “ 注入新鲜血液，实现品牌升级” or “最完美的品牌升级” but I still have no idea how to translate it suitably.

(a straight translation is not always the best choice for a slogan)

[image]
Any suggestion or answer would be appreciated and thanks in advance

**ADD:** The small text below the title says,

[image]

Comment: IMO, both the slogans in Chinese (done by you) reflect the English "the perfect boost" perfectly, what is your concern then?

Answer (score 1):

Base on the description, it is a marketing service that provides promotional contents on the most popular social media platforms

Here is my idea

'Perfect' means '完美', and the extended meaning is 全面 (all-around)

'Boost' means '促进',  and it is similar to 推動 (give impetus to) or 推廣 (promote)

You can translate the slogan 'The Perfect Boost' to '全面推動!' or '全面推廣!'

面 as in 面書 (Facebook)

推 as in 推特 (Twitter)

You can play around with these two character's font or color

Another idea is  to translate 'Boost' as '提升' (upgrade; promote) and translate 'The Perfect Boost!' as '全面提升!' which is a more forceful slogan that is closer to the original meaning

Comment: Thank you so much, Tang Ho! Have a beautiful day!:)

Answer (score 1):

Advertising is not my forte. (What is？He asks himself, hoping, in vain, for an answer.)

'boost' I suppose means 'boost your business', 'increase your sales'

sentence: 这是你的企业走向成功的完美契机。
slogan: 走向成功的完美契机 or just 走向成功

sentence: 我们一定能够帮助你的企业走向辉煌。
slogan: 走向辉煌的完美契机 or just 走向辉煌

sentence: 这是你的企业走向辉煌的完美助力。
slogan: 走向辉煌的完美助力

Happy Niu Year!